# Send mail via SMTP with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, email, smtp

I need send a email via SMTP with Cordova. Which plugin can I use to do this task? I already used plugins like cordova-plugin-composer, but the plugin opens a phone's app mail (gmail for example), and I need send the email directly from de app.

Thank u (and help x.x)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add cordova.jar in the project classpath

Step 2: Add cordova.js in the assets/www/js folder.

Step 3: create a new Java class called EmailComoposer.java

```
package com.dinesh.pb;
import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult.Status;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Html;
import com.dinesh.pb.utility.Mail;

@SuppressLint("ParserError")
public class EmailComposer extends Plugin {
public final String ACTION_SEND_EMAIL = "sendEmail";

 @Override
 public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray arg1, String callbackId) {
 PluginResult result = new PluginResult(Status.INVALID_ACTION);
 if (action.equals(ACTION_SEND_EMAIL)) {
 try {
 String message = arg1.getString(0);
 this.sendEmailViaGmail(message);
 result = new PluginResult(Status.OK);

 }
 catch (JSONException ex) {
 result = new PluginResult(Status.JSON_EXCEPTION, ex.getMessage());
 } catch (Exception e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 } 
 }
 return result;
 }

 private void sendEmailViaGmail(String body) throws Exception{
 Mail m = new Mail("From_email_address@gmail.com", "your password");
 String[] toArr = {"TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com"};
 m.set_to(toArr);
 m.set_from("FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com");
 m.set_body(body);
 m.set_subject("TEST SUBJECT");
 boolean sendFlag = m.send();

 }

}
```

Step 4. copy this Mail.java in package of your choice. My package name is com.dinesh.pb.utility.

```
package com.dinesh.pb.utility;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
 private String _user; 
 private String _pass; 

 private String[] _to; 
 private String _from; 

 private String _port; 
 private String _sport; 

 private String _host; 

 private String _subject; 
 private String _body; 

 private boolean _auth; 

 private boolean _debuggable; 

 private Multipart _multipart; 

 public Mail() { 
 _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
 _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
 _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

 _user = ""; // username 
 _pass = ""; // password 
 _from = ""; // email sent from 
 _subject = ""; // email subject 
 _body = ""; // email body 

 _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
 _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

 _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

 // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
 MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
 mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
 mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
 mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
 mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
 mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
 CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
 } 

 public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
 this(); 

 _user = user; 
 _pass = pass; 
 } 

 public boolean send() throws Exception { 
 Properties props = _setProperties(); 

 if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
 Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

 MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

 msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

 InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
 for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
 addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
 } 
 msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

 msg.setSubject(_subject); 
 msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

 // setup message body 
 BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
 messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
 _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

 // Put parts in message 
 msg.setContent(_multipart); 

 // send email 
 Transport.send(msg); 

 return true; 
 } else { 
 return false; 
 } 
 } 

 public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
 BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
 DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
 messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
 messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

 _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
 } 

 public String[] get_to() {
 return _to;
 }
public void set_to(String[] _to) {
 this._to = _to;
 }
public String get_from() {
 return _from;
 }
public void set_from(String _from) {
 this._from = _from;
 }
public String get_body() {
 return _body;
 }
public void set_body(String _body) {
 this._body = _body;
 }
@Override 
 public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
 return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
 } 

 private Properties _setProperties() { 
 Properties props = new Properties(); 

 props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

 if(_debuggable) { 
 props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
 } 

 if(_auth) { 
 props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
 } 

 props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
 props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
 props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
 props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

 return props; 
 }
public String get_subject() {
 return _subject;
 }
public void set_subject(String _subject) {
 this._subject = _subject;
 }

 // more of the getters and setters ….. 
 }
```

Step 5: Update the config.xml and add the details about the new plugin class EmailComposer.java. Mine looks like this – . Please update the package name value=”com.dinesh.pb.EmailComposer” with your package path.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<cordova>
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages --> 
    <access origin=".*"/> 
    <log level="DEBUG"/>
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="false" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    <plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    <plugin name="Temperature" value="org.apache.cordova.TempListener"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    <plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    <plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo" />
    <plugin name="EmailComposer" value="com.dinesh.pb.EmailComposer"/>
 </plugins>
</cordova>
```

Step 6: Create a new javascript file called email.js

```
var EmailComposer = function(){};
/*
cordova.addConstructor(function() {
    cordova.addPlugin("emailcomposer", new EmailComposer());
});
*/
EmailComposer.prototype.send = function (message){
console.log("Calling the send message");
cordova.exec(function(){ alert('feedback sent')}, 
    function(){ alert('feedback was not sent')}, 
    'EmailComposer', 
    'sendEmail', 
    [message]);
}
function sendFeedback(){
    window.EmailComposer.prototype.send("My message body");
}
```

Now as I mentioned earlier that I am using cordova-2.1.0.js/jar file there are subtle differences between the latest version and older version (cordova-1.9.0). If you are using older version you will need to uncomment the section cordova.addConstructorabove and instead of calling

```
window.EmailComposer.prototype.send("My message body");
Use this:
window.plugins.emailComposer.prototype.send(body);
```

If you do not use it then you may get error which would say that window.plugins is not defined. If you run into such issues use firebug and see what variables are defined under “window” variable.

Notice the method called “feedback()”. I am simply passing the user text as message body by capturing the input from user feedback TextBox. For simplicity I have just pasted a default Email body.

Step 7: Include the js file in your index.html file

```
// <!–[CDATA[
javascript" src="js/email.js">
// ]]>
```

Step 8: Include cordova js file in index.html

```
// <!–[CDATA[
javascript" src="js/cordova-2.1.0.js">
// ]]>
```

Step 9: Add three jar files for Java mail api – namely, Activation.jar, Mail.jar and Additional.jar in the libs folder and add it to the classpath. You can these files here.

Cheers!!